# Setting property of some pointer type

Tags: objective-c

If i have property defined on this way:

```
@property (atomic) int prop_int;
```

I can set its value on this way:

```
[c setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12345] forKey:@"prop_int"];
```

But if I have property which is pointer:

```
@property (assign) int *prop_int_ptr;
```

And I try to set value of this property on this way...

```
[c setValue:[NSValue valueWithPointer:(void*)int_ptr] forKey:@"prop_int_ptr"];
```

function won't work. I'm getting following error:

```
[<Car 0x10010a360> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key prop_int_ptr.'
```

Does anyone knows what is the way to set value of this prop_int_ptr property without setting it directly -> `c.prop_int_ptr = some_int_ptr;`
because I'm in situation when I can't use 'hardcoded' setting of property value. I need something more generic.

Comment: How did the situation arise?

Comment: Wrap the pointer into an `NSValue` object.

Answer (score 2):

Key-value coding does not support arbitrary pointers. Does your property need to be an int pointer? If you can, declare it instead as an `NSNumber`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *prop_int
```

That property will be key-value compliant.

Source: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2006/May/msg00343.html

Comment: Yes, I need int/float ,etc. Pointers as properties. Do you know is there some way simmilar to setValue:forKey which works for int pointer property?

Comment: You mean besides the obvious (i.e. `myObject.prop_int_ptr = &myInt;`)? Why exactly won't that work for you?

Comment: Because I'm writing lib for generic access to objective c from python. So I need some generic solution for this

Comment: In that case, I suggest you look over the Objective-C runtime reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html It's a native C API for introspecting the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: I know about objc runtime. BTW. I think I found solution for problem. From property attributes you can find out names of getters and setters functions, and if you have function names, problem is solved. You can call objc_msgSend, and get or set value of some property

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSNumber* instead of int*